# How can I find out what websites are used by people in a geographical area?

Tags: api, geolocation, saas

I'm interested in finding an API (or even a website that I could screen scrape) that would let me find out popular websites used in a geographical area.

For example, I'd like to be able to do a call like so:

```
getWebsitesUsedByPeopleNear(latitude, longtitude, maxDistanceAwayInKm, fromDate, toDate)
```

and it would return a list of websites like so:

http://www.google.com

...

By popular, I mean that sites have a high # of hits over a certain time period, where the hits are coming from people in the above described zone (lat,long,maxDistanceAwayInKm)

EDIT: I think ISP's, Analytics collectors, and browser extensions would all be able to get this type of data. For example, Alexa shows some of this type of data, but not at the level of detail I'd be interested in. There's appears to be too "global", and at a country level. I'd like to see it at a city level.

http://www.alexa.com/topsites/countries/CA

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to software development.

Comment: I think it is on topic, because I'm trying to find an API that reveals this data, a service (SaaS). What other SE site should it be asked on if so?

Answer (score 0):

The only people that would have such precise information are the providers of the websites itself. Even if there was such a service (I know none) it would be depending on all the companies who host websites giving away the data. I highly doubt that this would be the case, which makes any information you get unrepresentative.

Comment: Well, I think ISP's or Google or popular browser extensions would all have a chance to get this data, and I'm sure some of them want to resell it. I'd just like to know who they are so I can try/buy into their service ;-)